# How can I boot Debian from a USB drive from Windows 10?

Tags: debian, usb, uefi, bootable

This question isn't about creating a bootable USB; I already have. I followed Alexander Maru's instructions on [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/263615/how-to-create-a-bootable-debian-usb-drive-using-windows) StackExchange post. What I want to know is how to boot Debian from a USB drive. I already have Windows 10 installed; I don't want to dual boot. I want to be able to store files that I create on Debian on the USB as well. If I access the UEFI by doing System > Recovery on Windows, there is no option covering booting a different OS from a USB. How would I do that? I am on a laptop, so I can't access the UEFI by using any function keys while my laptop is starting up.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved it.

I disabled safe boot and then changed UEFI to Legacy Start, and it worked.

I still have one question, though. When I start the Debian boot menu up if I hit the install button, will it overwrite my Windows installation?

Comment: Not unless you explicitly follow the steps to erase your hard drive and install Debian as you would with any other OS. In fact you could actually shrink your Windows partition, make an EXT3/4 partition and install Debian to that, then you would be dual booted with relatively little effort. Just an fyi in case you change your mind about dual booting.